# how to redirect to a page on click in commandbutton

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:commandButton value="Enviar"  action="{!doSubmit}" onclick="redirect();"/>
```

javascript :

```
<script>
function abc()
{
window.location = 'www.google.com';
}
</script>
```

dosubmit is a method in controller which is doing case creation stuff.
THe page is not getting redirected. please provide a solution

Comment: abc() and redirect() are the same functions ?

Answer (score 3):

The [apex:commandButton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm) supports various events upon which it can call JavaScript (defined by the the `on...` attributes) and `oncomplete` is appropriate here:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Enviar" action="{!doSubmit}" oncomplete="abc();"/>
    </apex:form>
<script>
function abc() {
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Note that in theory your controller method could just return a `new PageReference('https://www.google.com')` but I can't get that to work and others have had problems with it too.

Comment: It would redirect in any case, either the operation done correctly or not. oncomplete will do its work.

Comment: @Ashwani Good point.

Answer (score 2):

You could have your `dosubmit` method return a PageReference instead of using javascript:

```
public PageReference dosubmit(){

    // create case, etc.

    PageReference pr = new PageReference('www.google.com');
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

---

This worked for me in a Developer Org in Firefox, Chrome, IE:

```
<apex:page Controller="tpc" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!dosubmit}" value="Do Submit" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class tpc{

    public PageReference dosubmit(){

        // create case, etc.

        system.debug('test');

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('http://www.baidu.com'); // google is blocked here
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        return pr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tested that - doesn't work for me in a dev org (and [doesn't work for others](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000grGqAAI) too).

Comment: @KeithC I read through the link, and it looks like people have just been having an issue redirecting to google. I never noticed the problem since no one here uses google and it is blocked anyways. It looks like in general this method of redirection should be fine though.

Comment: I tried a couple of URLs and neither worked - unclear to me what works and what doesn't and why.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `immediate="true"`.  Otherwise the page just seemed to do a postback.

```
<apex:commandButton immediate="true" value="Enviar"  action="{!doSubmit}" />
```

### Update

After more investigation it seems like this is only needed if there is an error during the postback.  In my case, I have a `<apex:hiddenInput />` where the binded value was a "DateTime" field.  Apparently, something about this caused my postback to fail.  After removing the Element my redirect works without `immediate=true`.
A easy way to tell if you post back is failing is to put a `System.Debug('Postback success')` at the top of your action method.  If you don't see this in the debug log, then you have an issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

set redirect parameters in the url by using :

```
 &retURL=%2f<the id of the case where you want it to redirect>
```